# How do I generate a new JavaScript array given the indexes and values in two other arrays?

Tags: javascript

I have two arrays, `arr1 = [1,2,7,9,10]` and `arr2 = [40,50,70,80,30]`. From these two arrays, I have a zero-filled array of length 15 that I want to populate using `arr1` as the indexes and `arr2` as the values: `[0,40,50,0,0,0,0,70,0,80,30,0,0,0,0]`

What is the code to do this?

Comment: Note that JavaScript uses zero-based indices for Arrays; so your first non-zero value – `40` – would be at index `0` not `1`. And what have you done to try and solve this problem yourself? Where did your solution go wrong, and in what way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution:

```js
var arr1 = [1,2,7,9,10]; // Add 0 to your array if you want first element of array3 to be replaced with arr2 element
    // If you want first element like in example this would be correct
    // var arr1 = [0,1,6,8,9];
    var arr2 = [40,50,70,80,30];
    var arr3 = [];  //[40,50,0,0,0,0,70,0,80,30,0,0,0,0,0]
    
    var arr3Length = 15;
    
    var arr2Counter = 0;
    
    for ( var i = 0; i < arr3Length; i ++ ) {
    
        if ( arr1.includes(i) ) {
            arr3.push(arr2[arr2Counter]);
            arr2Counter ++;
        } else {
            arr3.push(0);
        }
    
    }
    
    console.log(arr3);
```

JavaScript array starts with 0 element, not 1, so your first value is 0, not 40...

Comment: Thanks David. I would really want to keep the positioning the way it was in the example I gave, (that's format of the data I am working with) the first element in the arr1 map to the 1st element in arr2. though I understand Js array starts from 0, but this is not applicable to the data I am working with. I have been generating this on Excel macro before now and I want to implement it on Js. Thanks

Comment: Than just change the line `arr1.includes(i)` with `arr1.includes(i+1)` and that's it...

Answer (score 0):

Here is a succinct way to do it **without any for loop or if/else**. You first create an array withs 0s and the appropriate length, and then you fill the slots.

```js
const indices = [1, 2, 7, 9, 10];    // criteria 1
const values = [40, 50, 70, 80, 30]; // criteria 2
const length = 15;                   // criteria 3

const array = new Array(length).fill(0);
indices.forEach((idx, i) => array[idx] = values[i]);

console.log(array)
```

You could also calculate a default value for criteria 3 (length) if the length given is smaller than the last element of your index array.

```
lengthSafe = length < indices[indices.length-1] ? indices[indices.length-1] : length;
```

You should also make sure that your values array is not smaller than your indices array.

> Aslo, beware, JavaScript array indexing starts at 0, not 1!

If you consider 1 to be your first index, do this instead:

```
indices.forEach((idx, i) => array[idx - 1] = values[i]);
```

Comment: I really want this to start form 1,  I just want to maintain arr1 mapping to arr2, the way it was in the example, which means I would not want 0 to start in arr3. That's the format of the data I am working with.

Comment: I have updated my answer to include this case as well